# RepeatBehavior doesn't work in Expression Blend?

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, expression-blend

Is this just me or what? `RepeatBehavior` doesn't seem work for animations in Expression Blend 4. I have the following animation:

```
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" 
    Storyboard.TargetName="WaitDoc" RepeatBehavior="0:0:2">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.0" Value="0"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.1" Value="180"/>
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.2" Value="360"/>
</DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

I expect this animation to run for 2 seconds, but instead it runs only once when I click Play button in **Objects and Timeline** pane. I have tried values like **5x** too, getting the same behavior.

I don't want to run the entire project to test every minute change. The Play button SHOULD play it as defined. Am I missing something here?

**EDIT:** In addition, I just discovered that Blend also doesn't show any respect for `BeginTime` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
  <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames   
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children) [2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" 
Storyboard.TargetName="WaitDoc" Duration="0:0:2" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.1" Value="180"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.2" Value="360"/>
  </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Comment: Same behavior. Plus, I just discovered that Blend also doesn't have any respect for `BeginTime` attribute.

Comment: you've tried it with "Forever" ? , because in your code you wrote 
RepeatBehavior="0:0:2" , is that correct ?

Comment: Yep. I actually copy/pasted those two attributes (`Duration` and `RepeatBehavior`) from your code above.